# How to call pinentry from bash script

Tags: linux, terminal, stdout, pinentry

How to call `pinentry` from bash script so I am prompted for single input on the same terminal from which my script was invoked from and then pipe the entry to some other command via `stdout` for the sake of this question lets assume its `echo`.

I would expect the answer to be something along the lines of

```bsh
pinentry-tty <this is what I dont know> | echo
```

My question is not about:

- `gpg`
- `ssh`
- `git`
- How to use anything other than command line flavors of `pinentry`
- How to set environmental variable using `read -s`

Lets assume:

- I made it pass second google page
- I used `pinentry info`

What would be great if the answer would work for version I currently have on my system but I don't expect you to test it.

```
pinentry-tty (pinentry) 1.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 g10 Code GmbH
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

*I don't like the tone of my question but I am just trying to make it as clear as possible.*

Comment: maybe this Stackoverflow answer gives you something to workt with... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334080/444796

Answer (score 0):

The answer shared by Ichthyo's comment will work for you.
If you want to not use a GUI, and input PIN into terminal, do:

`sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry`

and choose `pinentry-curses`.

then, your script is the same from the SO answer:

```
tty=$(tty)

pwd=$(echo "GETPIN" | pinentry -T $tty | grep D)

pwd=${password#D }
```

you can also add more commands (found [here](https://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28pinentry%29Protocol)) separated by `\n`:

`pwd=$(echo "setdesc my program\nsetprompt please enter password:\nGETPIN\n" | pinentry -T $tty | grep D)`